# Connect to FaceBook without leaving web app

Tags: facebook, authentication, dialog

i'm stuck with fb login on mobile (js or php sdk) :)

I would like to create a fbconnect dialog without leaving my web app.

My goal is to create an app and lock the user in : don't allow the user to go outside (browser...).

Is there a way to only display a dialog with fields like user/password without any other links ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Please try http://stage.assistmelive.com and navigate to Networks->Send invite to see a demo. :)

Comment: Well thanks for your answer, however it's not helping, i'm talking about facebook login (and not share or invite).